# How to use array variable properly in gruntfile.js

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify, gruntfile

Trying to use a predefined array inside of a grunt file, thought using `this.js_paths` would work, but doesn't seem to work as I'm getting the error, "Cannot read property IndexOf of undefined" when it comes to trying to uglify the scripts.  How can I link the `js_paths` variable to the files `src` property properly instead of copying the array into the files.  Would like to define it separately at the top.  Is this possible?

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    // loadNpmTasks from package.json file for all devDependencies that start with grunt-
    require("matchdep").filterDev("grunt-*", './package.json').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        js_paths: [
            'inc/header1/js/*.js', 
            '!inc/header1/js/*.min.js', 
            'inc/header2/js/*.js', 
            'inc/header2/js/*.js', 
            '!inc/header2/js/*.min.js',
            'js/*.js', 
            '!js/*.min.js'
        ],

        uglify: {
            options: {
                mangle: true
            },
            build: {
                files: [{
                  expand: true,
                  src: this.js_paths,
                  rename: function(dst, src) {
                    return src.replace('.js', '.min.js');
                  }
                }]
            }
        },
        watch: {
            scripts: {
                files: ['inc/header1/js/*.js', 'inc/header2/js/*.js', 'js/*.js'],
                tasks: ['uglify'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false,
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify', 'watch']);
};
```

Preferrably would like to use the same array `js_paths` in the watch files (since it's required there), if that makes sense?  Still kinda new to using gruntfile.js

Comment: Btw. the glob pattern `'inc/header2/js/*.js'` has unnecessarily been specified twice in your `js_paths` array.

Comment: @RobC - Thanks, good catch.

Comment: Sorry, I've been so busy, I haven't tried it yet.  I have tried before with just `<%= js_paths %>` but haven't tried using it as a string.  Will test it and let you know.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Yes encasing `<%= js_paths %>` in quotes, (i.e as a string), is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize the [Templates](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#templates) syntax. It's described in the docs as following:

> #### *Templates*
>
> *Templates specified using `<% %>` delimiters will be automatically expanded when tasks read them from the config. Templates are expanded recursively until no more remain.*

Essentially, change `this.js_paths` to `'<%= js_paths %>'` in your `uglify` task.

For instance:

```js
// ...
uglify: {
  options: {
    mangle: true
  },
  build: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      src: '<%= js_paths %>',              // <-----
      rename: function(dst, src) {
        return src.replace('.js', '.min.js');
      }
    }]
  }
},
// ...
```

Likewise for your `watch` task too.

For instance:

```js
watch: {
    scripts: {
        files: '<%= js_paths %>',          // <-----
        tasks: ['uglify'],
        options: {
            spawn: false,
        }
    }
}
```